# An Alternative to <script> tag if resource don't get loaded

Tags: javascript, html

If a script resource could not be found by `<script>` tag

```
<script src="link.to.js"> <!-- 404 or 500>
```

Do I have an alternative to work around it naturally in html?

edit: the source it's in an external server, like 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, make sure your scripts return status code 200

Comment: If there was, how would you that method guess where the resource is or solve server errors? Question doesn't make logical sense

Comment: Can you elaborate on the conditions if a script file not loading? Is this a remote URL that you don't control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to fallback to another resource if the url fails to load if you are using [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), but that requires https. with service worker you have also the possibility to cache resources and make it available to work offline. (which is a good scenario for things like angular)

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        // If we got back a non-error HTTP response, return it to the page.
        return response
      } else {
        // An HTTP error response code (40x, 50x) won't cause the fetch() promise to reject.
        fetch('http://example.com/404')
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Another easier way would be to use something that i have seen used with jQuery a lot where if a cdn fails you can fallback to a local path

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

No, `<script src="link.to.js">` should work if you are linking the relative path correctly.

Make sure the path you provide to the file is correct.